# Restoring Wordpress's delete MAMP

Tags: wordpress, mamp

I was building a theme for a client of myne on mamp. When time came to update the theme on the development server, under appearances --> themes, I accidentally deleted the theme I was working so hard on! (I thought I was on the development server wordpress site, not on the local one)

I still have everything open as it was. Is there any way to recover wordpress' delete on my local server?

Comment: Time to get the server backups out. You're struggling without them - perhaps try a webhost that does it for you - I use [WPEngine](http://www.getwpengine.com) they provide staging areas as well as daily backups and one-click restores, but there are others as well.

Comment: Backups are so important for situations like these...

Comment: Indeed they are :(. Just be clear, this delete happened on my local computer, running on mamp. If you know of any way to get mac to spit back those files, would love you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the files are not in the Trash can, there are a few utilities available that may be of some assistance.

This article covers two of the most popular http://www.cultofmac.com/67472/how-to-undelete-files-in-mac-os-x-macrx/

In the event the link dies, the two recommended utilities are

- [SubRosaSoft FileSalvage](http://subrosasoft.com/software/filesalvage)
- [Prosoft Data Rescue](http://www.prosofteng.com/products/data_rescue.php)

Good luck!